# How to set parameters for new column in pandas dataframe OR for a value count on python?

Tags: python

I'm using a [some data from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/blue-plaques) about blue plaques in Europe. Many of these plaques describe famous people, but others describe places or events or animals. The dataframe includes the years of both birth and death for those famous people, and I have added a new column that displays the age of the lead subject at their time of death with the following code:

```
plaques['subject_age'] = plaques['lead_subject_died_in'] - plaques['lead_subject_born_in']
```

This works for some of the dataset, but since some of the subjects don't have values for the columns 'lead_subject_died_in' and 'lead_subject_born_in', some of my results are funky.

I was trying to determine the most common age of death with this:

```
agecount = plaques['subject_age'].value_counts()
print(agecount)
```

--and I got some crazy stuff-- negative numbers, 600+, etc.-- how do I make it so that it only counts the values for people who actually have data in both of those columns?

By the way, I'm a beginner, so if the operations you suggest are very difficult, please explain what they're doing so that I can learn and use it in the future!

Comment: you should start by plotting the data maybe a boxplot] and see what the range of the data is, if it makes sense, also a .describe on the dataframe can provide you with useful statistics. this analysis will help you understand the data and then you can clean it accordingly, if you find that there are missing values then fillNa could help or range maybe an issue  [some figures are in 10s some in 100s] etc etc but make sure the data is understood before excluding anything

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dropna` function to remove the `nan` values in certain columns:

```
# remove nan values from these 2 columns 
plaques = plaques.dropna(subset = ['lead_subject_died_in', 'lead_subject_born_in'])
plaques['subject_age'] = plaques['lead_subject_died_in'] - plaques['lead_subject_born_in']

# get the most frequent age
plaques['subject_age'].value_counts().idxmax()

# get the top 5 top five most common ages
plaques['subject_age'].value_counts().head()
```